# Want to assign user through Raspberry pi 4 B board dummy serial number which will store in EEPROM Atmel 178 24C256

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi4, atmel, eeprom

I have Raspberry Pi 4 B(4 GB RAM) Board. I want to assign a dummy serial number for storing the board in EEPROM Atmel 178 24C256. I also want to read by default the manufactured Serial number as well as the user through the assigned serial number.

Please help me with this question.